# How do I get a hex signiature like in the clamav database from a file with python

Tags: python, database, hex, virus

How do I get a hex signiature from a file that looks like this:

```
    Exploit.HTML.ObjectType:3:*:3c6f626a65637420747970653d222f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f
    HTML.Phishing.Bank-1:3:*:3c6d6170206e616d653d22{-36}223e3c6172656120636f6f7264733d22302c20302c20{4-12}222073686170653d22726563742220687265663d22{-160}3c2f6d61703e3c696d67207372633d226369643a
    Exploit.HTML.MHTRedir.1n:3:*:6d732d6974733a6d68746d6c3a66696c653a2f2f633a5c*21687474703a2f2f
    Exploit.HTML.MHTRedir.2n:3:*:646174613d226d732d6974733a6d68746d6c3a66696c653a2f2f(63|64)3a5c
    Exploit.HTML.MHTRedir.3n:3:*:7372633d226d732d6974733a6d68746d6c3a66696c653a2f2f633a5c
    Exploit.HTML.DragDrop:3:*:6265686176696f723a75726c282364656661756c7423616e63686f72636c69636b293b*666f6c6465723d227368656c6c3a
    HTML.Phishing.Bank-4:3:*:7468697320656d61696c20697320666f72206e6f74696669636174696f6e206f6e6c792e20746f20636f6e746163742075732c20706c65617365206c6f6720696e746f20796f7572206163636f756e7420616e642073656e6420612062616e6b206d61696c2e203c2f7072653e
    W32.MyLife.E:1:*:7a6172793230*40656d61696c2e636f6d
```

I know the signiature starts at the 3rd ':'
I'm trying to make a simple virus scanner in python with the clamav database, but i can't get a signiature like from the database...
I already tried binascii.hexlify(file.read()) but it gives a long hex string.

Comment: I think those signatures are made by humans, that is someone actually has to decide on the important parts of the sample then make a signature out of them.

Comment: You can start reading this guide: [Creating signatures for ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/signatures.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Paolo, i used the md5 file from the database.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is this. It can be written shorter, but I think this is more clear.

```
f=open('clamavfile','r')
signatures={}
for l in f.readlines():
    data=l.strip().split(':') #strip whitespace from the line, and split by :
    signatures[data[0]]=data[-1] # the filename is the first item, the signature is the last item
```

You could also use the re module if simply splitting by : is not enough.